# What causes page load delay after jquery loaded by Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, v8

What causes the delay after `jquery.js` is loaded? and after `jquery-ui-*.js` as well?  This is very consistant.  As you can see, all resources except the PHP file are loaded from cache -- this makes me believe it may be that Chrome is doing its V8 magic on them?

Interestingly, it doesn't occur with the `bootstrap-*.js` files.  Maybe they're much smaller?

[image: slow page load]

Comment: Isn't `media.php` (top line) still downloading during the delay you refer to after `jquery.js`? Wouldn't that account for _some_ of the delay?

Comment: Browsers parse the page as it arrives, not after.  Encountered JS files are parsed synchronously.  You can see that jquery.js is parsed immediately as the page begins loading (line 12), but jquery-ui (line 13) does not even begin loading from cache until at least 100ms after jquery.js is loaded.

Comment: execute JS itself also need time, one JS must finish execution before browser can process next one. In your char, 100ms for jQuery is not horrible.

Comment: I know browsers _parse_ the page top to bottom with JS scripts executed as they're found, but does that necessarily mean they stop _downloading_ the page while the JS is running?

Comment: browser will NOT stop downloading if its already started.. but will stop rendering and downloading new (since maybe after JS executed, the file does not need to download anymore) Thats why JS blocks everything. Because browser does not know what will happen after the JS so have to done with JS first before it can find out.

Answer (score 0):

jquery is a dependency of jquery-ui. Basically, jquery-ui can't be loaded until jquery is finished.

Comment: Yes, encountered JS files are parsed synchronously (based on order in page -- not "dependency"), but you can clearly see from the graph a more than 100ms delay between the loading of jquery and jquery-ui.  That's what I'm asking about.  A similar delay is seen between jquery-ui and bootstrap-alert.